# Sub instruction in assembly and the effect on CF and AF

Tags: assembly, subtraction

It seems that **CF** (carry flag) and **AF** (auxiliary flag) are tricky when using `sub` command. For example (first case is correct and easy to understand):

```
 AL=4CH, BL=29H          (C>9 , 4>2)
 SUB AL,BL     ; AL=23H       CF=0   AF=0

 AL=44H, BL=29H          (4<9 , 4>2)
 SUB AL,BL     ; AL=1BH       CF=0   AF=1

 AL=1CH, BL=29H          (c>9 , 1<2)
 SUB AL,BL     ; AL=F3H       CF=1   AF=0   ALSO SF=1

 AL=13H, BL=29H          (3<9 , 1<2)
 SUB AL,BL     ; AL=F3H       CF=1   AF=1   ALSO SF=1
```

Now take the second case for more details

```
 0100 0100
 0010 1001 -
------------
 0001 1011
```

There is no borrowing from AH to AL. So why the second case results in AF=1?

Regarding the third case, we borrow from AH. So in my opinion, CF=0 and AF=1. But the result is different from what I understand. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Intel Developer's Manual* gives some insight on the `AF` flag. It is the "Auxiliary Carry," used for BCD arithmetic. The manual says about it:

> AF — Auxiliary Carry flag — Set if an arithmetic operation generates a carry or a borrow out of bit
>   3 of the result; cleared otherwise. This flag is used in binary-coded decimal (BCD) arithmetic.

So in your example, there is no borrowing from `AH` to `AL`, but there *is* borrowing from the low 4-bit nibble in `AL` to the high 4-bit nibble in `AL`:

```
0100 0100
0010 1001 -
------------
0001 1011
     ^
     Borrow needed in low nibble because '1001' (9) is greater than '0100' (4)
```

Unless you are using BCD arithmetic, you shouldn't have to use the `AF` flag.

`CF`, on the other hand, will be set if there is a carry or borrow from the most significant bit of the result, whether the instruction uses 8, 16, or 32 bit operands.

The *Intel Developer's Manual* says about `CF`:

> CF — Carry flag — Set if an arithmetic operation generates a carry or a borrow out of the most significant
>   bit of the result; cleared otherwise. This flag indicates an overflow condition for
>   unsigned-integer arithmetic. It is also used in multiple-precision arithmetic.

Comment: So AF is used for 4 bits. CF is used for 8 bits. What about 16 bit? I mean AX with carry. How to distinguish 8 and 16 bits with carry?